# Having problems using ScrollView

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having a very hard time trying to understand Kivi's ScrollView, is there anyone who can help me? The thing is that I have a page with a label, multiple switches and a button to confirm the choices of those switches, how do I make a working ScrollView for this?

Answer (score 0):

check this tuto:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPaeoSv0rjo&t=23s

but instead of a `Label` in the `ScrollView` use a layout like GridLayout or something and remember that the scrollView accepts one widget as a child so u have to add a layout scrollview and layout it self can accept many widgets

```
ScrollView:
    size: # whatever u need
    pos: # whatever u need
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_y: None       ## this is mandatory
        id: my_scroll                
        height: self.minimum_height
        cols: 1
```

and in ur main.py u can just:

```
self.ur_widget = Button(text='btn', size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x= 1.0)
self.ids.my_scroll.add_widget(self.ur_widget)
```

u can play with this and play with layouts to find whats best suited for u: